New install of Spamassassin in Ubuntu 24.04 won't start
I'm replacing my Ubuntu 22.04 mail server with a new 24.04 one.  I've gone through the entire setup with no issues until . . . I install SpamAssassin but it won't start.  More specifically, It can't find the startup file.  I've scoured the inter-webs but haven't found anything useful.  Has anyone seen anything like this or better yet know how to resolve?
I found one other person with the exact question I have but no replies so far.
When I try to start the new installation (Ubuntu 24.04):
xxxx@xxxxxxx:/etc# systemctl start spamassassin
Failed to start spamassassin.service: Unit spamassassin.service not found.

What I see on my existing Ubuntu 22.04:
xxxx@xxxxxxx:~$ systemctl status spamassassin
● spamassassin.service - Perl-based spam filter using text analysis
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/spamassassin.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-11-13 04:01:34 UTC; 1 week 0 days ago
     . . . 


In Ubuntu 24.04 the actual package that contains the spamassassin is called spamd.
$ apt show spamd
Package: spamd
Version: 4.0.0-8ubuntu5
Priority: optional
Section: mail
Source: spamassassin
Origin: Ubuntu
Depends: spamassassin (= 4.0.0-8ubuntu5), systemd | rsyslog | system-log-daemon
Breaks: spamassassin (<< 4.0.0~0.0svn1883440-2)
Replaces: spamassassin (<< 4.0.0~0.0svn1883440-2)
Homepage: https://www.spamassassin.org/

So the command to start it is systemctl start spamd.

(updated to reflect the name change highlighted by Gerald Schneider)

It can't find the startup file

You can list the files in the package with dpkg -L spamd.
It is possible that this contains a systemd service unit or sysV init script which is on the filesystem, but systemd hasn't found it yet - systemctl daemon-reload will fix this.
But you already have a working system which is telling you where the unit file is - did you check?
